# optical chemical structure recognition from images

Tags: object-recognition, ocr

I want to recognize name of the chemical structure from the image of chemical structure, like in the given image it is benzene structure I want to recognize that it is benzene from the image(I should be able to recognize all these structures as benzene) What way I could follow to achieve this? (like this given any structure I want to recognize the name of it) [image] .

Comment: your question has no question mark (?). What is it that you want to know?

Comment: I want to recognize these benzene structures as benzene

Comment: Ok, and what is your question?

Comment: What way I could follow to achieve this? or is there any similar work I could follow

Comment: Do you want to only recognize if it is benzine (i.e. is it benzine yes or no) or do you want to recognize the name of any structure?

Comment: Yes!! I want to recognize the name of any structure given in the image

Answer (score 2):

## What way I could follow to achieve this?

1. Create a dataset with `image`-`label` pairs.
2. Create a classification model.

I don't think you will find any algorithm "out-of-the-box" for you to use.
You might have a look at some paper to see the kind of approaches they have.

I would recommend you look at these:

- https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1802/1802.04903.pdf which uses convolution neural nets and a heatmap as an attention mechanism. It even deals with noisy images.
- https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs231a/prev_projects_2016/optical_recognition_of_chemical_structures.pdf which tries to identify hand-drawn structures. It uses a sort of edge detection algorithm for recreating the hand-drawn structures.

Comment: Thank You!! @Bruno GL, I will go through these papers.

Comment: @LalitVyas great I could help. If you think like your question has been answer, feel free to accept this answer.

Comment: sure @BrunoGL :)

Comment: @lalit vyas did they work?